# Rename added sheets based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet named on today's date 20200701. I need to make copies of this sheet and the names should be successive days i.e. 20200702, 20200703 etc.

What I wrote generates the copy. It doesn't rename the tabs.

```vb
Sub Copy()
    Dim J As Integer
    For J = 1 To 20
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Next J
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the macro recorder. It's a gift.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim J As Integer, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For J = 1 To 20
        ws.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Format(Date + J,"yyyymmdd") 
        'or for workdays....
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = _
                   Format(Application.WorkDay(dt, i), "yyyymmdd")
    Next J
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and reply. Can it be done for business date instead of the normal date?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.workday

Comment: Thanks for the document, Tim. I am completely amateur in VBA. What changes need to be done to incorporate Workday in this VBA Code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim LValue As String
    For J = 1 To 20
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        LValue = Format(Date + J, "yyyymmdd")
        ActiveSheet.Name = LValue
    Next J
End Sub
```